# How to get scripted programs governing game entities run in parallel with a game loop?

Tags: c

I recently discovered [Crobot](http://crobots.deepthought.it/home.php) which is (briefly) a game where each player codes a virtual robot in a pseudo-C language. Each robot is then put in an arena where it fights against other robots.

A robots' source code has this shape :

```
/* Beginning file robot.r */
main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        /* Do whatever you want */
        ...
        move();
        ...
        fire();
    }
}
/* End file robot.r */
```

You can see that :

1. The code is totally independent from any library/include
2. Some predefined functions are available (**move**, **fire**, etc…)
3. The program has its own game loop, and consequently is not called every frame

My question is: How to achieve a similar result using scripted languages in collaboration with a C/C++ main program ?

I found a [possible approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11843/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-II) using Python, multi-threading and shared memory, although I am not sure yet that it is possible this way. TCP/IP seems a bit too complicated for this kind of application.

Comment: Google for scripted languages that can be run from an existing application - Python, Lua and PascalScript come to mind.

Comment: @KromStern I thought the same, however, it appears [Crobot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crobots) is a compiler and virtual machine application. So, it appears it's compiling its own executables and then running them on a virtual machine? I'm not sure of the details. However Crobot did it, it's likely far more advanced than is necessary today, and a scripting language would be superior way to implement this now.

Comment: @Jim, do you actually care how Crobots did it? Or do you just want to know how you can implement something similar? Typically questions that are "how X did Y" are off topic here because only X can answer that. In this case, the source code is GPL, so you can find out exactly how Crobots did it on your own, but I suspect you'd like to know how you can do it on your own instead.

Comment: @Byte56, you're right, I was planning to try something similar. And as you say (and Krom Stern says), it might be easier to use scripting languages. I am still curious about Crobot's case, maybe I will investigate further but it does not seem to be the best way of doing things today.

Comment: Short answer is : using a *parser* to 'understand' the codes and one *finite-state machine* per robot to make it run. You might look also about what is an *interpreter*. (on wikipedia, a tutorial, ... )

Comment: @Jim Maybe you can modify the question to ask what you're actually interested in, or remove the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to implement it is to use Python, threads and TCP/IP. What you need is :

1. A main application managing the game itself
2. A python thread for each bot
3. A python script to connect a bot to the main application (sending/receiving messages)

What you do ***not*** need (in this particular case) is :

1. Embed Python in the main application or vice versa
2. Mutex, semaphore or any other stuff preventing the memory to get corrupted (thanks to TCP/IP)

I can suggest the following design which worked for me :

[image: Game design picture]

Using this design, I came up with a very simple interface for the bots and a fairly playable game. A bot looks like :

```
# Beginning of file name_of_bot.py
def main(bot):
    while True:
        bot.move()
        ...
        scanResult = bot.scan()
        ...
        bot.rotate(15)
        ...
# End of file name_of_bot.py
```

...where you can do anything you want since it is a Python script (provided that you keep the main function's signature as it is) !

**Update**: For those interested, [here is the link to the actual game on GitHub](https://github.com/Zer0Zer0Huit/PythonBot).

Comment: As this answer is very specific, I am still open to accept a more generic (constructive) answer.